# How do I use the Tableau Method?

Tags: logic

I have to do different exercises concerning the tableau method. So for example I need to show if a formula $X$ is tautology or not. So I have to check if all branches of $\neg X$ are closed right? But what do I do if the branches do not close? Have I found a boolean assignment such that $X$ is false?
And I also have a different kind of exercise with not one formula, but a set of formulas, so do i have to negate all of them and use the tableau method again?
I am really confused right now and would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Correct*.

The tableau method is a *refutation* procedure; if all the branches of the tableau close, then the initial formula is *unsatisfiable*.

Thus, if we start with $\lnot X$ and the tableau closes, this means that $\lnot X$ is *unsatisfiable*, i.e. $X$ is a *tauitology*.

If the procedure ends and a branch does not close, this branch determines an assignment of truth values to the *atoms* that satisfy the initial formula: in our case $\lnot X$.

But if $\lnot X$ is satisfied by a suitable assignment, this means that, for that assignment, $X$ is falsified, and so $X$ is not a tautology.

---

With a set of formulas, we can have two types of question:

*(i)* to check if the last one (the *conclusion*) is *implied* by the others (the *premise*).

In this case, we have to consider the premises with the *negation* of the conclusion; if the tableau closes, this fact proves that the conclusion is impklied by the premises.

*(ii)* to check if the set of formulas is *satisfiable*.

In this case we apply the tableau to the original set of formulas; if the tableau is opne, this means that the set of formulas is satisfiable.

Comment: And if I know that $X$ is no tautology, how do i find an assignment such that $X$ is false? Can't I do that with the tableau method?

Comment: @JohnyHunter - YES; apply the tableau to $\lnot X$. $X$ is not a *tautology*, and thus $\lnot X$ is *satisfiable*: the tableau will end with an open branch that produce a falsifying assignment for $X$.

Comment: Ok that answered my question, thx a lot!